# Jquery remove old functions and on click handlers

Tags: jquery

I have a page with button on it that loads a modal.

In this modal I display data.

This data can for example consist of 5 entries of a certain table
When an entry gets removed, the data is refreshed. Same thing for when an entry is added.

Now when I close the modal by clicking outside of it and reopen it. The functions that were attached to the first modal are still there and firing. 
So if I add an entry. The ajax and scripts that do that are fired/called twice.

Code :

```
            $(document).on('click','.remove_team',function(){
                var tournament_id = $(this).data('tourn');
                $.ajax({
                    url :'./organisations/waiting_list/team_assignement.php',
                    type :'POST',
                    data : {
                        action : 'remove_team',
                        team_id : $(this).data('team'),
                        tourn : $(this).data('tourn')
                    },
                    success : function(){
                        LoadParticipantList(tournament_id);
                    }
                })
            })
            function LoadParticipantList(tournament){
                $.ajax({
                    url :'./organisations/waiting_list/team_assignement.php',
                    type :'POST',
                    data : {
                        action :'fetch_team_participants',
                        tournament : tournament
                    },success : function(res){
                        res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);        
                        $("#counter_"+tournament).html(res.count);              
                        $("#div_"+tournament).html(res.teams);
                    }
                })
            }
```

What is the correct way to remove a click handler and then directly add it again so the ajax fires?

Comment: What is purpose of two ajax calls ?

Comment: where's the modal code? All you are showing is ajax code

Answer (score 0):

I guess may use unbind, sample:

```
$("#foo").unbind( "click" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add a click event outside your modal popup. this click events stops the treatments that you don't want to have ...

```
$('documents').bind('click', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('#your_modal_id').length == 0) {
        //click happened outside the modal popup : stopping treatments
    }
});
```

also add a stop propagation events to avoid unwanted treatments to be run ...

```
$('#your_modal_id').click(function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method will do the job.